# Need bash shell script for reading name value pairs from a file

Tags: shell, properties-file

I have a file like

```
name1=value1
name2=value2
```

I need to read this file using shell script and set variables

```
$name1=value1
$name2=value2
```

Please provide a script that can do this.

I tried the first answer below, i.e. sourcing the properties file but I'm getting a problem if the value contains spaces. It gets interpreted as a new command after the space. How can I get it to work in the presence of spaces?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365871/code-for-parsing-a-key-value-in-in-file-from-shell-script

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
while read -r line; do declare  "$line"; done <file
```

Comment: Ok I figured this works  while read -r line; do declare  "$line"; done <file  even if there are spaces in teh values.

Comment: @kurumi, please consider editing this to add quotes. It *is* faulty without them.

Answer (score 38):

If **all** lines in the input file are of this format, then simply sourcing it will set the variables:

```
source nameOfFileWithKeyValuePairs
```

or

```
. nameOfFileWithKeyValuePairs
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting problem if the value contains spaces. It gets interpreted as a new command after the space. Please tell how to get it working in the presence of spaces.

Comment: I have dots in my keys (e.g. `data.dir=/path/to/data/dir`). It gives errors such as `Command not found` or `No such file or directory` depending on the value. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: As noted elsewhere here, 'source' works for many cases but a) may have security implications, and b) will not function for values that have for example "$" in them.

Comment: Why you should not source file (big security risk) - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433245/364638

Answer (score 20):

Sourcing the file using `.` or `source` has the problem that you can also put commands in there that are executed. If the input is not absolutely trusted, that's a problem (hello `rm -rf /`).

You can use `read` to read key value pairs like this if there's only a limited known amount of keys:

```
read_properties()
{
  file="$1"
  while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
    case "$key" in
      "name1") name1="$value" ;;
      "name2") name2="$value" ;;
    esac
  done < "$file"
}
```

Comment: This is great as it matches keys with dots: `"key.subkey") name1="$value" ;;`

Comment: Note that your property file needs a trailing new line `\n` character on the last line or it won't get read.

Answer (score 19):

if your file location is `/location/to/file` and the key is `mykey`:

```
grep mykey $"/location/to/file" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 7):

Improved version of @robinst

```
read_properties()
{
  file="$1"
  while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
    case "$key" in
      '#'*) ;;
      *)
        eval "$key=\"$value\""
    esac
  done < "$file"
}
```

Changes:

- Dynamic key mapping instead of static
- Supports (skips) comment lines

A nice one is also the solution of @kurumi, but it isn't supported in busybox

And here a completely different variant:

```
eval "`sed -r -e "s/'/'\\"'\\"'/g" -e "s/^(.+)=(.+)\$/\1='\2'/" $filename`"
```

(i tried to do best with escaping, but I'm not sure if that's enough)

Comment: This is a good one, but it does not read the last line. How to fix?

Comment: @Andrew good point, didn't know about this. Seems to be something in `read -r key value` which I cannot even reproduce without the loop. Any help out there?

Answer (score 6):

suppose the name of your file is `some.properties`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Sample shell script to read and act on properties

# source the properties:
. some.properties

# Then reference then:
echo "name1 is $name1 and name2 is $name2"
```

Comment: While true, this should come with the big blinking red warning label that reads "EVAL! EVAL! YOU'RE USING EVAL HERE!" unless there is absolute undoubted control over the input file.

Comment: Is there any difference if I source as .some.properties and . ./some.properties

Answer (score 1):

```
    filename="config.properties"

# Read the file and extract key-value pairs
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    # Skip empty lines or lines starting with #
    if [[ -z $key || $key == \#* ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Trim leading/trailing whitespace from key
    key=$(echo "$key" | awk '{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")} {print $0}')

    # Extract the value after the first equals sign
    value="${line#*=}"
    
    # Assign value to the variable dynamically
    declare "$key"="$value"
done < "$filename"

# Print the variables
echo "key1: $key1"
echo "key2: $key2"
echo "key3: $key3"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#### Use shdotenv

dotenv support for shell and POSIX-compliant .env syntax specification
https://github.com/ko1nksm/shdotenv

```
Usage: shdotenv [OPTION]... [--] [COMMAND [ARG]...]

  -d, --dialect DIALECT  Specify the .env dialect [default: posix]
                           (posix, ruby, node, python, php, go, rust, docker)
  -s, --shell SHELL      Output in the specified shell format [default: posix]
                           (posix, fish)
  -e, --env ENV_PATH     Location of the .env file [default: .env]
                           Multiple -e options are allowed
  -o, --overload         Overload predefined environment variables
  -n, --noexport         Do not export keys without export prefix
  -g, --grep PATTERN     Output only those that match the regexp pattern
  -k, --keyonly          Output only variable names
  -q, --quiet            Suppress all output
  -v, --version          Show the version and exit
  -h, --help             Show this message and exit
```

Load the .env file into your shell script.

```sh
eval "$(shdotenv [OPTION]...)"
```