# How to get the value using shell script in hadoop mapper

Tags: bash, hadoop

I want to process PCAP file,then use WholeFileInputFormat.
The input of the map is `<filename,content>`.
How to get the content by using shell script?

Comment: The input of the map is <filename,content>

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please provide sample input and your desired output.

Comment: The input of the mapper is a file like "key \t this is the value,and I  \n want to get the value. " . The output I want to get is the part of that file, like "this is the value,and I  \n want to get the value.", how to use shell scripts to do it?

Comment: My question looks like this ,but the value is the content of a file,There are many lines of the file [Links]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365871/code-for-parsing-a-key-value-in-in-file-from-shell-script

Comment: So, given a filename, return the contents minus a "word \t" on the first line?

Comment: yes,That's what I mean,I want the content of the TAB later,how to do this using shell script? thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# test file:
echo -e "foo bar\tthis is\nthe rest of the content" > file

contents=$( sed '1s/[^\t]*\t//' file )
label=$( sed '1{ s/\t.*//; q }' file )
```

You must quote the variables to preserve whitespace.

```
echo "$label"
echo "$contents"
```

You should always quote variables unless you know specifically why you shouldn't

Comment: When I echo $contents,I get "this is the rest of the content".But I want to keep this contents in 2 rows,in other words,I wish to retain the '\n'.

Comment: Thank you for your patience to answer，thanks very much.

Comment: Contents is a hexadecimal file content,how to retain \x00?