# Read strings from file and store them in multiple variables with bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I've been looking through a lot of posts here but none of them can completely solve this out.

I've got a configuration file (ie: default.conf) with several values in it:

```
id: 2
type: food
name: potato
quantity: 34
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a bash script to read the config file and assign every single value after the ":" (2, food, potato, 34...) to multiple variables for posterior use in that script.

Comment: Variables are meant to store singular strings. Store multiple strings in an array!

Comment: Sorry, I meant in multiple variables

Comment: @ChandanKumar Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need bash shell script for reading name value pairs from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990575/608639) and [Code for parsing a key/value in in file from shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15365871/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a associative array for this. This requires bash 4 or higher.

Loop over the file and use string manipulation from bash to assign the variables in your associative array.

```
declare -A conf_vars; while read line; do conf_vars[${line%:*}]=${line#*:}; done <default.conf
```

You can now use the variables by using e.g.: `${conf_vars[type]}` which in your example gives food.

EDIT:
SO syntax coloring does not understand that in this case # does not indicate a comment. Just ignore it.

Comment: I recommend using `${line%%:*}` in case the line had more colons in it.

Comment: This one works perfect. I needed to use the double % as suggested by @PesaThe as I had a few more colons.

Answer (score 0):

Using `read` with `:` delimiter:

```
declare -A vars
while IFS=: read -r lvalue rvalue; do
    vars[$lvalue]=${rvalue# }
done < data
```

`${rvalue# }` removes the extra space. If the space is required, use just `${rvalue}`.

---

**Output:**

```
declare -p vars
declare -A vars=([id]="2" [quantity]="34" [name]="potato" [type]="food" )
```